# Assign Hostname to Intranet IIS Website

Tags: iis, networking, lan, intranet

I'm trying to create a website with IIS that is accessible from the Intranet (LAN) of my corporation. This website will display various infos.

Currently, to connect to the webpage, I have to enter `192.168.1.24` (The address of the server running IIS) into any computer that is on the same LAN. It is my hope to have employees type in `http://CorporationName.com` or even `CorporationName` to be brought to the website.

I believe the solution to my problem may lie in editing the hosts file to redirect `CorporationName` to `192.168.1.24`. Would that change take place on the Server, or on each client machine that is trying to access it? The latter doesn't really seem feasible / convenient.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to get someone (IT department, maybe) to assign that machine a permanent IP address and a name in the internal DNS server.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer. I'd be deploying a server into many corporations that would need this feature, so for us to have them go to this trouble for a small web page is a bit of a PITA. :P Thanks for the answer, I'll accept first thing tomorrow! 5PM! :)

Comment: Nothing stopping you from buying a domain name from $ANYPROVIDER (Not GoDaddy) and running a very simple hostname like "foo.dtimatt.com" and pointing that at 192.168.1.100 and then having "client2.dtimatt.com" and pointing that at 192.168.1.102

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on your setup. While you are correct, editing the HOST file to direct "companyname" to 192.168.XXX.XXX will work but you would have to set this in every client PC.

If you are on a typical domain setup where a domain controller is in charge of DNS then you should be creating the appropriate entries in DNS on the domain controller using the management console and the DNS snap-in. A great explanation of DNS and the setup is located here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738619%28v=ws.10%29.aspx.